# Embeding google map onto my site and letting people draw shapes on it, then allowing them to share a link to a map with shapes drawn

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I know there is a google functionality that allows people to draw shapes on a map and then share this map. like here:
https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=1L37dUobu31lZrdbldzLoDJDSRILJn8k&ll=51.213995648981474%2C-0.9215977500000061&z=10

I wonder would it be possible to use google draw library to add such map to my page, and then let people to draw shapes on it and then generate a link to map with shapes drawn like I  showed you in a link above.
My code so far:

```
        <script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=drawing&callback=initMap"> </script>
<script>
  var shapez = []; // Initialize an array to store the drawn shapes
  var map; // Declare map variable globally to access it in multiple functions
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: { lat: 53.55916479477714, lng: -0.4925998147353304 },
      zoom: 8,
    });
    const drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
      drawingControl: true,
      drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
        drawingModes: [
          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        ],
      },
      markerOptions: {
        icon: "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png",
      },
      circleOptions: {
        fillColor: "#cddef7",
        fillOpacity: .7,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        clickable: false,
        editable: true,
        zIndex: 1,
      },
    });
    drawingManager.setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
      shapez.push(event.overlay);
      updateLink();
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
      updateLink(); 
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
      updateLink(); 
    });
  }
  function encodeMapData() {
  var features = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < shapez.length; i++) {
    var shape = shapez[i];
    var feature = {
      type: 'Feature',
      geometry: {
        type: shape.type,
        coordinates: []
      },
      properties: {}
    };
    if (shape.type === google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
      var path = shape.getPath();
      for (var j = 0; j < path.getLength(); j++) {
        var latLng = path.getAt(j);
        var coords = [latLng.lng(), latLng.lat()];
        feature.geometry.coordinates.push(coords);
      }
    }
    // Add other shape types as needed
    // ...
    features.push(feature);
  }
  
  var data = {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: features,
    center: {
      lat: map.getCenter().lat(),
      lng: map.getCenter().lng()
    },
    zoom: map.getZoom()
  };
  return JSON.stringify(data);
}
function updateLink() {
  var shareLink = document.getElementById("share-link");
  var data = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(shareLink.href.split("?q=")[1]));
  var shapes = data.features;
  
  // Clear existing shapes on the map
  for (var i = 0; i < shapez.length; i++) {
    shapez[i].setMap(null);
  }
  shapez = [];
  
  // Recreate shapes from GeoJSON data
  for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
    var shape = shapes[i];
    var coords = shape.geometry.coordinates;
    var type = shape.geometry.type;
    var newShape;
    if (type === google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
      var path = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < coords.length; j++) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[j][1], coords[j][0]);
        path.push(latLng);
      }
      newShape = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: path,
        // Add other options as needed
      });
    }
    // Add other shape types as needed
    // ...
    newShape.setMap(map);
    shapez.push(newShape);
  }
}
  function shareMap() {
    var shareLink = document.getElementById("share-link");
    var url = "https://www.google.com/maps?q=" + encodeURIComponent(encodeMapData());
    shareLink.href = url;
  }
  window.initMap = initMap;
</script>
<a href="#" id="share-link" onclick="shareMap()">Share map</a>
```

But the link I generated, when opened throws an 'error":
[not really an error but more like a failed search result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K47sK.png)

I tried reading google documentation, chat GPT, whimping and yelling

Comment: There is no link between My Maps and the Maps JS API. And no way that I know of that allows to create and open a maps link with shapes or anything else. That said you could do all that on your own website.